# Creating a button with which a running process can be killed or terminated

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, borland-c++

I would like to add a button to my form with which a running process (loop which runs several thousand times) can be terminated if the user wishes to stop the process for any reason or load another file.

The program has a part which performs an interpolation for multiple cases and creates and saves a text file for each case. Once the process is launched (this is done by pressing a button after the necessary files have been loaded), it starts running and cannot be stopped until it is completed. The duration of this process could be anything between minutes and hours depending on the size of certain files.

I have copied a code snippet from the part which is called when the button is pressed (changed names and certain parts and ommitted what follows the first if block as it is irrelevant here).

```
void __fastcall TMapperForm::bt_InterpolationClick(TObject *Sender)
 {
 int i;

 if(someflagused == true)
 {
      different_cases_total = 0;
       for(i=0; i<something_counter; i++)
       {
       CleanStuff();
       FunctionReadingFiles(list_of_stuff->Items->Strings[i]);
       InterpolatingFunction();
       different_cases_total+= no_cases;
       }
 }
}
```

As written above, I would like to create another button which can kill/terminate the process. My main problem is that when the program runs, it freezes and I see no way to interrupt the loop.

Is there any way to add a button which remains active even when the loop is running and can terminate the process when clicked?

Comment: To allow the user interface to still be active while you are performing some other action , you must either use threads, or pump Windows messages inside your loop. If you decide to go with threads, launch your intensive process in a thread, and leave the main thread to handle the user interface.

Comment: @M.M Yeah I had an inkling that this has to do something with threads. My knowledge in programming is fairly limited, I have learnt the basics of C++, VCL and BCB recently to be able to work on this project. I will look into that, thanks. Could you add anything specific to your advice, pseudocode or a link to an example where both the multithreading and the kill process is shown? Is this what I have to do essentially (using the Stop or Terminate part with a button)?: [C++ Builder Multithreading](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30382&seqNum=6),

Comment: Remy will be along with some sample code any time now. That article's really old.  You should mention which version of C++Builder you are using.

Comment: (Remy Lebau? Hahaha, I love this community, he has commented on my previous BCB-related question before.) I'm using BCB 4.0. The project I'm working on requires me to change some features on a tool which was written 10-15 years ago, hence the old version.

Comment: You don't need us to write examples for you. There are many examples of threading that you can find with a websearch.

Comment: Your loop should have time to interact with system, it was kind of '`Application.DoEvents()` (I haven't licence BCB in last years)

Comment: If `InterpolatingFunction();` goes away and doesn't come back for a long time, then message-processing solutions won't work

Comment: @M.M Yes, I am looking at that option now, but I'm afraid that won't work in this case, which leaves the multithreading.

Comment: @M.M: I did not see this question until just now, there are already several good suggestions and answers, so no need for anything from me ;-)

Comment: @laika have a look at this [Application->ProcessMessages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35032754/2521214) especially the last bullet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it you are interpolating inside **VCL** which means that **VCL is frozen**

The **VCL/WinProc** function is stopped until your computation is done so no components will work (no buttons,timers,sliders,...)

**How to repair it?**

1. **move the computation to thread**

   Threads are great for this but you need to do some synchronization and

   **Avoid access of VCL components and visual stuff WinAPI calls from the thread !!!**

   So if you need to draw something pass it to your window and then draw from App main thread (inside timer or something).

   Inside the thread scan some `volatile bool stop;` and if `true` break from for loop. Then on start of thread set `stop=false;` and on your button click event `stop=true;`
2. **move your computation to `OnIdle` event of application**

   just add `void __fastcall MyOnIdle(TObject* Sender, bool &Done);` inside your form class header file `(*.h)` and then to your form `(*.cpp)` add:

   ```
       void __fastcall TForm1::MyOnIdle(TObject* Sender, bool &Done)
        {
        for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) // iterate so many times it does not slow the App too much
         {
         if (computation_done) { Done=true; Application->OnIdle=NULL; return; }
         // here iterate your computation
         }
        Done=false; // if you let Done be false all the time the CPU would be 100% loaded !!!)
        }
   ```

   now when you want to start the computation you just do `Application->OnIdle=MyOnIdle;` and for stopping it do `Application->OnIdle=NULL;` change `TForm1` to class name of your form.

   **OnIdle event is part of VCL main thread so you can access any VCL stuff at will** so **no problems** with **access violations** and **invalidating WinAPI** like there are with threads also you do not need to use the `volatile` anymore
3. **Can use VCL timers**

   it is almost the same as `OnIdle` event just instead of stopping after `1000` (or any other number) loops stop after `time` is passed. For that you need to scan time for example with

   ```
       LARGE_INTEGER i;
       QueryPerformanceFrequency(&i); double freq=double(i.QuadPart);
       QueryPerformanceCounter(&i); double cnt=double(i.QuadPart);
   ```

   `freq` is in [Hz] and `cnt` is actual count so take one `cnt0` value at start of timer inside loop take another one `cnt1` and

   ```
   if ((cnt1-cnt0)/freq>double(Timer1->Interval)*0.001*0.9) break;
   ```

   this way you will run almost the time your timer is firing so the app should not slow down too much on any **CPU**. If you are running OS without these counters (Win9x ...) you can still use `RDTSC` or some OS time api with high enough resolution

**[Notes]**

Only the first option is capable of using your interpolation as is for the bullets **#2,#3** you need to rewrite it so it can be computed in iterative process until it is done.

Answer (score 1):

The is no problem to give TButton. Problem is to be prepared to events. Such loop catch activity and Your app don't respond to events.

```
bool BreaKtheLoop = false;

void __fastcall TMapperForm::bt_InterpolationClick(TObject *Sender)
 {
 int i;

 if(someflagused) // redundant comparison == true)
 {
   ..
       for(very long loop)
       {
           ...
           Application->ProcessMessages();
           if(BreaktheLoop )
              break;
       }
 }
}
```

an in new button Click 
set variable to true;