# ProcessMessages on OnShow Event c++ builder

Tags: c++, message-queue, show, c++builder, c++builder-6

I'm using c++ builder (bcb6) and on:

```
FormShow
```

event there is:

```
Application->ProcessMessages
```

I would like to know what exactly the responsibility of:

```
Application->ProcessMessages
```

What exactly it did? and when we shall use by that? when it can cause exp.?

Thanks!

Comment: finally finished editing. btw **BCB6** is the worse from the series (too many bugs) if you have the option switch to **BCB5, BDS2006** or newer (have no experience with the later ones). **BDS2006** have free licences for 100 years but their servers are down. I am sure you can download its reg file from the net somewhere. The compiler is way better except [this bug](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016392/2521214) which can be easily avoided. And the **CodeGuard** implementation saves me a lot of time (sadly not usable on really complex apps)

Comment: There are also down sides like: you need at least 2-core CPU for IDE to avoid occasional freezes for a bit (its just annoying) and avoid to watch too big arrays (it freezes IDE for good) not to mention the IDE needs a lot of frameworks and latelly also x64 fix for restarting IDE due to windows font security update.

Answer (score 0):

1. **The BDS 2006 IDE help states for `Application->ProcessMessages` this:**

   Interrupts the execution of an application so that it can process the message queue.

   Call `ProcessMessages` to permit the application to process messages that are currently in the message queue. `ProcessMessages` cycles the Windows message loop until it is empty, and then returns control to the application.

   Neglecting message processing affects only the application calling `ProcessMessages`, not other applications. In lengthy operations, calling `ProcessMessages` periodically allows the application to respond to paint and other messages.

   `ProcessMessages` does not allow the application to go idle, whereas `HandleMessage` does.
2. **so what for it is?**

   It allows to respond to **Windows messages** in case your app is blocking normal **WindProc** operation (inside **VCL**). For example if you got some lengthy computation on some event that takes minutes the application would freeze (can not click,move,resize,redraw,... until operation is done). If you once in a time call `ProcessMessages` from that long loop (timers would also not work during that time) that will allow to make your app responsive during this time... so it will not freeze.

   I usually use [threads or OnIdle event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32755440/2521214) instead for such computations so the main App is not blocked at all.

   I am reluctant to believe that `OnShow` is called during such blocking. I would place the `ProcessMessages` inside the computation that blocks the App (if the computations is inside the `OnShow` then it is **OK** otherwise it would be useless. Anyway `OnShow` is called only if your Form is turning to `Visible` do not mistake it for `OnActivate` or `OnPaint`.
3. **small example**

   Create empty form app and place 2 buttons in it (`btStart,btStop`) then create on click event for them as following:

   ```
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   bool go=false;
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void __fastcall TForm1::btStartClick(TObject *Sender)
       {
       int i=0;
       for (go=true;go;)
           {
           Caption=i; i++;
           Application->ProcessMessages();
           Sleep(100);
           }
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   void __fastcall TForm1::btStopClick(TObject *Sender)
       {
       go=false;
       }
   //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

   When you start app and click `btStart` it will start incrementing integer in `Caption` field of the `Form1` and stop when you click `btStop`. during counting the App is still responsive (can click,move,resize,...). You need to stop before closing App is possible (destructors wait for returning from all events). if you rem out the `Application->ProcessMessages();` then the App will count but will never stop because you can not click on `btStop` due to the freeze. To close click on the **IDE** and press **CTRL+F2**.

Hope it clears things a bit.